# FTP transfer with WinSCP - Getting "Opening session using command-line parameter in scripting is deprecated. Use 'open' command instead."

Tags: ftp, winscp, synchronize

I use this code to **copy** files from the server **to a local** folder

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ftp://Emna:root@localhost
synchronize local C:\Users\User\Documents /Projets/SPR/Sources
exit
```

I run the script using this command:

```
winscp.com /RemoteScript.txt
```

But it doesn't work.

I'm getting this error:

> Opening session using command-line parameter in scripting is deprecated. Use 'open' command instead.

What can I do to copy files from the server to a local folder using a script?

Comment: The error states the server rejects SFTP, but accepts FTP.

Comment: Yes,but  it doesn't copy the files from _/Projets/SPR/Sources_ to _C:\Users\User\Documents_

Comment: Post error messages as text, not as image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`/script` switch to specify the script file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting):

```
winscp.com /script=RemoteScript.txt
```

For general overview, see the [guide to automating transfers from FTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).